beamer section slide with name in colorbox centered in the frame
I'm working on a presentation for my PhD defense and planning on experimenting with beamer.
I'm not an expert with LaTex and wanted to know if with \usetheme{Boadilla} it comes an option to set a vertically centered box with the section name in it as per here with a similarly simple code.
At the moment this is the code I'm using, MWE below, and the problem I'm facing when attempting some alternatives is that I never have a box surrounding my text even with the following code from an example I found:
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

MWE
\documentclass[169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{bground}{HTML}{0074c0}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \fill [color=bground] (0,0.86\paperheight) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=anti-flashwhite}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-.08in}{}

\AtBeginSection[] {
      \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Outline}
      \tableofcontents[currentsection,sectionstyle=show/shaded]  
      \end{frame}
}
\AtBeginSubsection[] {
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsubsection,sectionstyle=show/shaded]
   \end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
    \sectionpage
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overview}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\section{METHODS}

\end{document}


Please only ask one question pre post.

You are still loading unnecessary packages in your preamble. Please narrow your code down to a minimal reproducible example before posting a question.

Please also choose a title which reflects the actual problem so that future users with the same problem will be able to find it.

You wrote, "I was thinking whether it could be useful to make use of subsubsections" [in my beamer presentation]. Why? Are you trying to impress your committee with fancy colors and backgrounds? Word from the wise: They almost certainly won't care one bit about flashiness. Why not focus on the content of your presentation instead? Just pick a basic (i.e., non-flashy) beamer theme, stick with it, and focus on the content. The fewer subsubsections, the better. The optimal number of subsubsections employed in any beamer presentation may well be zero...

@Mico I see, in any case my intent was to don't go beyond three. However, at the same time I wished to have something neat and presentable with a consistent visual scheme. I will follow your advice, it probably best to just have few main concept in each section. Thanks!

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz sorry, I will clean-up and fix the post according to what is relevant. I won't make use of subsubsections and so focus on the third point only.

Please don't strike through all the outdated text, but actually write a question focused on the problem so that one does not need to scroll tons of unrelated text to find what the current question might be. The time necessary to figure out what your questions are actually about is disproportionally high compared to actually answering them.

You commented, "I wished to have something neat and presentable with a consistent visual scheme". In order to create a neat and presentable beamer presentation with a consistent visual scheme, you don't need subsubsections (and likely no subsections either).

The default section page automatically has a box around the section title. In some themes, the default colour is empty, but it can be changed to make the box visible:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\setbeamercolor{section title}{bg=green}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
    \sectionpage
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{METHODS}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}



thanks a lot. I doubted the box was there and completely white and just needed to be colored, or it was completely missing. I guess is the first? Thanks again, I also made the question less wordy.

@Matteo Thanks for editing your question, it is better now. However your code still has all the stuff about tocs and no section page. And it has still potential to be boiled down, e.g. does the background matter for the section page?

I merged the first code block in the MWE so that running it shows the issue with this specific theme. I removed also irrelevant part from the ToC in the example. Is there by any chance a way to remove the Section 1 from the frame, or is it something embedded in the theme?

@Matteo Either redefine the section page template or a quick and dirty hack: change the section title colour to match your background
